# Add a new tab/page in Teamcity build page

Tags: plugins, continuous-integration, teamcity

i want to add a new tab for each build of Teamcity. My aim is to show some custom statistics, information and graphs/reports on that tab.

I couldn't find any clear information, i try to write plugin but couldn't find any solution to put a tab into build page(mostly admin level links examples)

What is solution of that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this.
1. you can use the 'Statistics' tab in each build for publishing the reports and charts that you want to publish
2. you can create your own build level or a project level report tab to publish the artificats or even any report in html format, for instance. By this second way it would be a customized version of their of reporting and you can strucute the report, in many ways.